# Google Web Search API returns only the first 100 result set

Tags: api, search, google-api

Is there a way to search and retrieve all results for a particular query in Google? I want to use Custom Search API, but the starting index of the result set can be 99 at most (http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/using_rest.html) Which means I can retrieve only the first 100 items. In my case, there are around 4000 items in the result set.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve about 1000 results: 100 pages with 10 results each. See: http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/using_rest.html#query-params

It seems as if you can't go beyond that, though.

UPDATE: I stand corrected. It's only 100.

Comment: I believe 100 is the actual limit, not 1000. It says "This API can return the first 100 search results, in chunks (pages) up to 10 search results long. You can specify the page of search results to return using the start and num query parameters." This is not the same as "up to 100 items in up to 10 pages" as you interpret.

Comment: You are right. I looked at the num and start parameters and thought that num means amount of results PER PAGE and start means which of the up to 100 pages you want. But start defines the search result you want to start with. Sorry.

Comment: this is not an actual answer, it adds nothing to what's in the question itself

Comment: Actually if you read this documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference , you can see the actual max is 10000. You just have to set `max-results=10000`

Comment: The above response of max-results=10000 may work for Goggle Analytics but that is a separate API and does not pertain to the googleapis customsearch API. I tried it anyway with max-result=1000 and it is a definite no go and returns:{
      "error": {   "code": 400,  "message": "Invalid Value"  }

Comment: Is this maximum limit applicable for paid api too ? somebody please comment

Answer (score -3):

BTW - The new Google API can return more than 10 results per page, limited by 20 results per page, using num=20

http://www.google.com/cse/docs/resultsxml.html

Comment: the disclaimer on top of the page specifies "This page refers to the XML version of the Custom Search API, which is available only to Google Site Search customers" so it doesn't apply to the OP case