# Google Place Search API in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, google-places-api

I have implemented the google place search API in IOS and enabled the API in the developer console and used the below code but its shows error that "***This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 122.173.223.114, with empty refer***"

After regenerate the API key its shows API key is expired and after sometime its shows the same above errors. Please help someone.

```
  -(void) queryGooglePlaces: (NSString *) googleType {
// Build the url string to send to Google. NOTE: The kGOOGLE_API_KEY is a constant that should contain your own API key that you obtain from Google. See this link for more info:
// https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#Authentication
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&types=%@&sensor=true&key=%@", appDel.objLocationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, appDel.objLocationManager.location.coordinate.longitude, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", appDel.currenDist],googleType, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];


//Formulate the string as a URL object.
NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];

// Retrieve the results of the URL.
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
 }
     -(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
//parse out the json data

if (responseData==nil) {

}else{
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

//The results from Google will be an array obtained from the NSDictionary object with the key "results".
NSArray* places = [json objectForKey:@"results"];

//Write out the data to the console.
NSLog(@"Google Data: %@", json);
}
 }
```

Comment: There is some limitation og Google Place API http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008689/google-web-search-api-returns-only-the-first-100-result-set

Comment: I done this using alternative GMSAutocompleteViewController library of google

Comment: so ist there any limitation in GMSAutocompleteViewController?

Comment: Limitation is not for GMSAutocompleteViewController. Limitation for google place api i.e. 1000 hit per day.

Answer (score 3):

I did it with use of AFNetworking class Try this one,

```
#define kGoogleAutoCompleteAPI @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=%@&input=%@"


-(void)getAutoCompletePlaces:(NSString *)searchKey
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    // set request timeout
    manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 5;

    NSString *url = [[NSString stringWithFormat:kGoogleAutoCompleteAPI,GoogleDirectionAPI,searchKey] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

    NSLog(@"API : %@",url);
    [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
         [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

         NSDictionary *JSON = responseObject;
         predictions = [NSMutableArray array];

         // success
         AutomCompletePlaces *places = [AutomCompletePlaces modelObjectWithDictionary:JSON];
         [arrSuggestionData removeAllObjects];

         if (!arrSuggestionData) {
             arrSuggestionData = [NSMutableArray array];
         } 
         for (Predictions *pred in places.predictions)
         {
             [arrSuggestionData addObject:pred.predictionsDescription];
         }

         [self.Tbl_suggestion reloadData];

     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
}
```